# Prove $|e^{z^2+1}| \le e^2$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration, line-integrals

Actually what I want to prove is $|\int_{D} e^{z^2+1} dz| \le 2\pi e^2$ for $D$ = the unit circle (centred at origin).

What I know is $|\int_\gamma f(z)dz| \le AB$ for $A$ the length of $\gamma$ (for whatever $\gamma$ you need eg  smooth, continuously differentiable, simple/injective, Jordan, whatever) and $B \in \mathbb R$ assuming $|f(z)| \le B$ for all $z \in image(\gamma)$.

Then obviously $2\pi$ is the length. As for the $e^2$, **I think of 2 ways.**

---

**Way 1**: We have $|z^2+1| \le |z|^2+1 \le 1+1=2$ and then somehow $|e^{z^2+1}| \le e^{|z^2+1|} \le e^2$.

I believe in general for any $f: G \to \mathbb C$ for any subset $G$ of $\mathbb C$, we have that $|e^{f(z)}| \le e^{|f(z)|}$ because for $f=u+iv$, we just do $|e^{f(z)}|=e^{u(z)}$ and $e^{|f(z)|}=e^{\sqrt{u^2(z)+v^2(z)}}$.

**Question 1**: Is this correct?

---

**Way 2**: $$e^{z^2+1} = e^{x^2-y^2+1}e^{i(2xy)}$$

$$=e^{x^2-y^2+1} [\cos(2xy) + i\sin(2xy)]$$

Then

$$|e^{x^2-y^2+1} [\cos(2xy) + i\sin(2xy)]|$$

$$= |e^{x^2-y^2+1}| |\cos(2xy) + i\sin(2xy)|$$

$$= e^{x^2-y^2+1} |\cos(2xy) + i\sin(2xy)|$$

$$= e^{x^2-y^2+1} $$

$$= e^{x^2-y^2+1} \le e^2$$

because $x^2-y^2+1 \le 2$ because $x^2-y^2+1=x^2-(1-x^2)+1=2x^2 \le 2$ because $x^2 \le 1$ because $x \le 1$

**Question 2**: Is this correct?

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral theorem for holomorphic functions? $\int_{D} e^{z^2+1} dz$ is zero.

Comment: @MartinR lol thanks. but it seems we're supposed to use the inequality i stated above

Comment: thanks @MartinR both ways are correct? well my doubt is that i tried $|e^z=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)| \le 1+1=2$ at 1st but then i remembered liouville's theorem. so now i'm just making sure i'm not falling into any traps. anyway, you can post as answer to say i'm correct in both ways and then include the little bit and cauchy's integral theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is correct.
$$
 |e^w| = e^{\operatorname{Re}(w)} \le e^{|w|}
$$
holds for all complex numbers $w$, so
$$
 |e^{z^2+1}| \le e^{|z^2+1|} \le e^{|z|^2+1} = e^2
$$
for $z = 1$.

However, this is not needed to estimate the integral. According to [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), $\int_{D} e^{z^2+1} dz$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

Essentially, $e^z = e^{x+yi} = e^x (\cos(y) + i \sin(y))$, therefore $|e^z| = |e^x||\cos(y) + i \sin(y)| = e^x$.

That is, $|e^z| = e^{\text{Re}(z)}\le e^{|z|}$ as $\text{Re}(z)\le |z|$ and $e^x$ is a monotone function for real $x$. This justifies the step $|e^{z^2+1}|\le e^{|z^2+1}|$ in your first method.

Answer (score 0):

Proof that the integral is 0 by Cauchy's theorem:

---

Note: we're not yet allowed to say derivative of holomorphic are holomorphic or even that they are continuous. hell.

---

Step 0: Parametrise $C_1(0)$ by $\gamma: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb C, \gamma(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ s.t. $C_1(0)=image(\gamma)$.

Step 1: $f(z)=e^{z^2+1}$ is entire as a composition of 2 entire functions $e^{z}$ and $z^2+1$

Step 2: $\mathbb C$ is open in itself, connected and simply connected.

Step 3: $f'(z)=2ze^{z^2+1}= 2zf(z)$ is continuous on $\mathbb C$ because $f'(z)=2zf(z)$ is entire because each of the following are entire: $2z, f(z)$ ($f(z)$ is shown to be entire in Step 1) and because products of entire functions are entire.

Step 4: $\gamma$ is a piecewise smooth path since $\gamma$ is a smooth path since both its real and imaginary parts are smooth since each of the following are smooth on $2 \pi$: $\cos(t), \sin(t)$ (because they are smooth on $\mathbb R$) and because sums and products of smooth functions are smooth.

Step 5: $\gamma$ is closed because $\gamma(0)=(1,0)\stackrel{aka}{=}1+0i=1=\gamma(2 \pi)$.

Step 6: Therefore, by Steps 1-5, the integral is zero by the version of Cauchy's theorem below with $D = \mathbb C$.

- Let $f: D \to \mathbb C$ be analytic for open, connected and simply connected $D \subseteq \mathbb C$. Suppose $f'$ is continuous on $D$. Let $\gamma$ be a piecewise smooth closed path with image in $D$. Then $\int_{\gamma} f = 0$.

QED

Comment: Cauchy's integral theorem (in the form that I know of) only requires that $f$ is holomorphic, I don't see why step 3 is needed. Everything else looks ok to me.

Comment: @MartinR 'Note: we're not yet allowed to say derivative of holomorphic are holomorphic or even that they are continuous. hell.' but thanks!